# Shopware block doesn't get registered

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I started to learn how to create a custom block in shopware 6. To do this I setup a development environment using [ddev](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/quickstart/#shopware). This wasn't as easy as it should've been, since I needed version 6.4.2.0 of shopware.

So my shop is running locally and I started creating an extension and followed this [guide](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/content/cms/add-cms-block.html) to add custom blocks to the "Shopping Experiences", which resulted in my own [plugin](https://github.com/Myrmod/shopware6_content_elements).

After having installed the extension I called `ddev exec ./bin/build-administration.sh` to "register" my custom blocks. The command finished successfully.
However, I am not seeing my block anywhere. So I have two questions:

1. What am I missing in my extension?
2. How can I properly debug this issue?

I tried to follow the guide I had as strictly as possible. Since I don't know how to properly debug shopware, I only copy/pasted all files and their respective contents according to the guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue and I am perplexed.

In an effort to keep my code "dry" I exported the config:

```js
export const config = {
  name: blockName,
  // label: 'sw-cms.blocks.text.text.label',
  label: "My Image Text Block!",
  category: "text-image", // TODO: add custom category
  component: `sw-cms-block-${blockName}`,
  previewComponent: `sw-cms-preview-${blockName}`,
  defaultConfig: {
    marginBottom: "20px",
    marginTop: "20px",
    marginLeft: "20px",
    marginRight: "20px",
    sizingMode: "boxed",
  },
  slots: {
    left: "text",
    right: "image",
  },
};
```

and used them like

```js
import { config } from "../index";
import template from "./sw-cms-block-my-image-text-reversed.html.twig";
import "./sw-cms-block-my-image-text-reversed.scss";

const { Component } = Shopware;

/**
 * @private since v6.5.0
 * @package content
 */
Component.register(config.component, {
  template,
});
```

This however doesn't work, I have to use the names of the component or preview that I want to register as a full string.

I don't know why that is, maybe there is some magic happening which I don't understand or I have simply made a mistake somewhere. I can't find it though.

For now I will write the whole name of the component/preview file.
I found the cause by an error that has been thrown in the browser console.